# What is the size of Polygon Mumbai chain in GB?

Tags: blockchain, testnets, nodes, the-graph, blockchain-size

I want to know the total size of the chain because I am running a The Graph Node on an EC2 instance and I have to allocate resources to that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the size of Polygon Mainnet?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/147823/what-is-the-size-of-polygon-mainnet)

Comment: No, I am asking about Polygon Mumbai and that other question is not yet answered correctly either. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of **March 21, 2023**, the total size of the Mumbai testnet is about **229.07 GB**.
You can find this information on the Polygon snapshots website: https://snapshots.polygon.technology

Hope this helps