# What is the current size of a copy of the entire Polygon Mainnet chain?

Tags: blockchain, polygon, mainnet, the-graph, blockchain-size

I want to know the total size (in `GB` or `TB`) of the database on a node that has a copy of the entire Polygon Mainnet chain, so I can allocate resources for a production instance.

How can I know that? I don't want the recommended size I should have, I want the actual size.

Comment: Would you explain what exactly do you mean? Are you looking to determine current size of the blockchain?

Comment: Yes, current size of the blockchain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of **March 22, 2023**, the total size of Polygon Mainnet is about **1269.05 GB**. You can find this information on the Polygon snapshots website: https://snapshots.polygon.technology

Answer (score 1):

Hi developer advocate from [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) here.

That depends on the client and the mode of the node(light node/full node/archive node).

To run a full node using Polygon's own [bor](https://github.com/maticnetwork/bor) client takes minimum:

```
RAM: 16-32 GB
CPU: 8-16 core CPU (For AWS: t3.2xlarge)
Storage: 2.5TB to 5TB SSD (make sure it is extendable)
```

[[Source]](https://wiki.polygon.technology/docs/operate/technical-requirements/#:%7E:text=Minimum%20Hardware%20Configuration%E2%80%8B&text=RAM%3A%2016%2D32%20GB,make%20sure%20it%20is%20extendable)

For an archive node:

```
RAM: 64 GB
CPU: 16-core CPU
Storage: 10+ TB
```

Erigon is another popular EVM client, it usually takes fewer resources for archive mode. You can find its system requirement [here](https://wiki.polygon.technology/docs/operate/erigon-client).

Usually running a node by oneself is quite costly. Syncing a full node will take multiple days, and you need to spend a lot of effort to maintain it. I strongly encourage you to try RPC providers like [us](https://chainstack.com/build-better-with-polygon/) instead of setting it up on your own.

It is just much cheaper and hassle-free.

Comment: Thank you but I just want to know the actual size of the chain in GB.

Comment: The Chain itself can't be measured in the size of storage volume. If you really want a number, 2.5 TB is the minimum storage size required for a bor node according to the official doc.

Comment: Why can't the chain be measured in the size of storage volume?

Comment: A blockchain network is simply multiple connected nodes. Those nodes work together to achieve consensus - meaning the same state for account balance, smart contract, etc. Transactions are packed in blocks, when nodes receive a new block they update their local database.

Comment: That's why I am talking about that local database, what is the actual size of it right now? Just to estimate resources... I get my question is technically wrong but I thought it was going to be understood.

Comment: So when you say the size of polygon mainnet, it doesn't really make sense. Because each node leverage on different storage systems and the storage size may valid. Technically, you can have an excel sheet with all the account information + state information and hire a bunch of people manually interpret block information and update the excel sheet. But that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Then I have already given you the answer, for a bor node, 2.5 TB is the minimum storage size.

Comment: For a full node, this 2.5 TB includes All state information(account, smart contract, storage) + the most recent 128 blocks.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments but, again, that's the recommended size. I just want to know the ACTUAL size as of today.

Comment: I don't have the exact number right now. The number I provided is actually the minimum system requirement. Base on my best knowledge, you should follow it.

Answer (score 0):

The actual size of a blockchain can be measured for archive node size since archive nodes include literally everything on-chain.

This [article](https://medium.com/protofire-blog/tame-the-behemoth-or-how-to-run-an-archive-blockchain-node-b1fc13591ab5#:%7E:text=Polygon%3A%20%7E16%20TB,Fantom%3A%20%7E4%20TB), dated July 2023, says it's bigger than 16 TB. As of today, I would guess 20+ TB.